# Basic Python variable function not working?

Tags: python, variables

I am learing Python and tried to input variables but they did not give the expected outcome. I was hoping for it to change "boy_name" into "bobby", but it did not.

Here is the code

```
print("there was a boy named " + boy_name + " ")                          
print("there is a boy named timmy")


boy_name = "Bobby"
```

Comment: Each line of code is run from top to bottom; when the first line is executed, `boy_name` has not been defined. You have to define it before you use it. In this case you could just move the `boy_name = "Bobby"` code above the two `print`s. But you said you wanted to "input variables" - which to me means you want the user's input, so that you can display a user-chosen name. If that's the case, you'd use Python's `input()` function (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)). But without clarification on what you mean by "input", I'd say this is not answerable.

Comment: _but they did not work_ Saying that something "didn't work" is not very helpful.  If you're getting errors, **post them**.  If you're getting unexpected output, **post it** and explain how it's different from what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the variable before it declaration.

Carry your variable declaration at the top of the first print function

**For Example**

```py
boy_name = "Bobby"
print("there was a boy named " + boy_name + " ")                          
print("there is a boy named timmy")
```